# trap <action> SIGTERM not working for shell script in docker container

Tags: docker, shell, sh

I have a docker container that is starting its PID1 with a shell script.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/home/run.sh"]
CMD ["start"]
```

Script file

```
#!/bin/sh

_term() {
  echo "Caught SIGTERM signal!"
  stop()
}

trap _term SIGTERM

# trap stop SIGTERM


start() {
    echo 'Server starting...'
    sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
    sudo /etc/init.d/renderd start
    nohup /home/mapmon.sh > /dev/null &
}

stop() {
    echo 'Server stopping'
    pkill mapmon.sh
    sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
    sudo /etc/init.d/renderd stop
}
for arg
do
    $arg;
done

if ! tty --silent
then
    sleep infinity
fi
```

But when I try to stop the docker container, the script doesn't handle/catch the SIGTERM signal.

On startup following logs are printed but stop/catch SIGTERM logs are never printed.

```
Jun 28 12:12:53 hac-sbatra-1 docker/maps: Server starting...
Jun 28 12:13:48 hac-sbatra-1 docker/maps: Server starting...
Jun 28 12:14:39 hac-sbatra-1 docker/maps: Server starting...
```

Is there something missing in the code?

Comment: It's easier to `trap _term EXIT` and don't care which signal.

Comment: That's not working either. `_term` is not getting called.

Comment: `stop()` is not how you call a function in Bash. Please create an [MCVE]. Does your script terminates, there is no code in your scripts, it only defines functions, - what does it do? What is the base image, does it sets `STOPSIGNAL`?

Comment: If you need three different programs running in containers, it's usually better to launch three separate containers; tools like Docker Compose can help you get these all set up in a single command.  This is doubly true if you're mixing databases and stateless application components.

Comment: How are you starting the container (is there a `docker run -i` option)?

Comment: Updated the question to show what script does after starting the processes.

Comment: As an aside, the `sudo` commands are useless here; surely this is running as `root` already.

Comment: The syntax error in the `stop()` call - as pointed out above by @KamilCuk - is probably the full explanation as to what's wrong here.

Comment: It doesn't work if I simply use the commented code. `trap stop SIGTERM`. That should catch the sigterm and call stop, right?

Comment: Are you sure that stopping the container sends a `SIGTERM`?